# rails 4 Heroku rake assets:precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

on application.rb I have set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
and set `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` but I'm getting an error while pushing the app.

```
   Bundle completed (16.84s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2014-03-05T02:02:01.768165 #902]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a7c8577-cd26-45c3-8c52-5c933f0f7e20/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-147f3f6e098736e89ffab2c15cfbef06.eot
```

Comment: please post your error, check that your local ruby version is the same as Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

`Config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` is no longer needed in Rails 4 and `heroku labs:enable user-env-compile` have been deprecated.